# Receive headers in Flutter Web/Alternate to Query Paramters

Tags: flutter, http-headers

tldr: I have a Flutter web page that I need to be able to do a couple things. First, it must accept auth information about the consumer accessing the site. Second, it must be able to use 'deep links'.

Longer version:

The website must be able to accept authentication information. Currently, we are using urlParamaters to pass this information to the web app. This means we're using `usePathUrlStrategy();` in the main method to be able to access the parameters. Retrieving the parameter looks like this:

```
  String? token = Uri.base.queryParameters['token'];
```

We also need to be able to directly access links like this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/details/870?token=##############
```

Where `details` is the name of the route and `870` is the item number for which we are retrieving details. This means that `details` is a static part of the url and `870` is dynamic.

The problem is this: We can directly access links if we turn off `usePathUrlStrategy();`, but then we can't access the auth token from the URL parameter any more. This means we can retrieve information from:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/#/details/870?token=##############
```

This only works when the website has previously received and saved token information. When we do this, the token is not updated/received by Flutter. The `?token=##############`is effectively dropped from the URL.

We *can* convert url parameters to headers that are passed to the website, but I can't find any documentation on how to read those headers.

Questions:

- Is there a way to read incoming headers in Flutter Web?
- Is there a way to accept both URL Parameters and Deep links?